# Javascript regex reject leading 0 in numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

This code below will prevent leading 0 from user input. It will only accept any number from `0-9` and reject any leading zero for example `019`. However the regex is not accepting `0` such as `101` or just `0`. How can I accept `0` in my input?

```
console.log('input', e.target.value)

const z = /^[1-9]$/g;
if (!z.test(e.key)) {
  console.log('match', e.target.value);
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

This is accepted input:

```
0
101
1110
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `^[1-9]\d*$`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Regex**: [`^(?!0\d)\d+$`](https://regex101.com/r/Kgg2zM/1)

```js
function myFunction() {
  console.clear()
  var s = document.getElementById("input").value;
  console.log(/^(?!0\d)\d+$/.test(s));
}
```

```html
<form action="javascript:myFunction()">
  <input id="input" type="text" name="math" value="0"><br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
const regex = /((^[1-9][0-9]*$)|(^[0-9]$))/g
```

This acceps your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

A number should either start with a non-zero or be a zero.
So, the regexp may be

```
const z = /^(?:[1-9][0-9]*|0)$/g;
```

or

```
const z = /^(?:[1-9]\d*|0)$/g;
```

Comment: You may be thinking about `^([^0]\d*|0)$`

Comment: Exactly! Thank you

Comment: Except  [^0] isn't ok , it may be any chars (not necessariry aa digit)

Comment: Yes, and I thought input type may be validated beforehand.